# Security lug nut key with a rotating washer on top

Tags: vw, key, security, wheel-lugs

I have lost my security log nut remover for a 2010 VW Routan station wagon, and it has a rotating washer in the front I tried every tire shop possible to remove it they said they cant, I don't know what to do. 
I tied dodge dealer, VW dealer and everybody else I could think of but no luck

Comment: VW dealer should be able to sell you one, what did they say?

Comment: A rotating picture? Could you post a picture @JoshChavol?

Answer (score 0):

If you can’t get one then the only option left is to drill it out - but make a protector so you don’t damage the wheel and also control the depth...